# How is an artifact's final dependency scope in a project determined?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

With reference to https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

> Each of the scopes (except for import) affects transitive dependencies in different ways, as is demonstrated in the table below. If a dependency is set to the scope in the left column, transitive dependencies of that dependency with the scope across the top row will result in a dependency in the main project with the scope listed at the intersection. If no scope is listed, it means the dependency will be omitted.

[image]

I can't visualise the above. Please clarify for me on the following points:

First question: Assume A depends on B which in turn depends on C. Which does "a dependency is set to the scope in the left column", "transitive dependencies of that dependency with the scope across the top row" and "result in a dependency in the main project" each refer to in the above example?

Question 2: I have a `lib` folder which contains `compile` and `provided` subfolders. A has a compile dependency on B and a provided dependency on C. B has no dependency. C has a provided dependency on B. Which folder should B be located in?

Answer (score 0):

Transitive dependency can be inferred as

[image: Dependency]

will result in

[image]